# @font-face in GWT

Tags: gwt, font-face

I was trying to use following code with GWT 2.2.0:

```
//in my UiBinderFile
<ui:style field="myStyle" src="MyCssFile.css"/>
.
.
<g:Label ui:field="aboutMainHeader" styleName="{myStyle.decorFont}"></g:Label>
```

and also in MyCssFile.css in same directory as UiBInder xml,

```
//entire MyCssFile.css
@font-face {
    font-family: cool_font;
    src: url('cool_font.ttf');
}
.decorFont{
    font-family: cool_font; /* no .ttf */
}
```

When I try to compile this, I get some NPE in UiBinder parser, right afer call of method that does font face parsing. I don't know what is wrong. Has anyone tried face-fonts with GWT, and could you please post working example?

Thanks...

Comment: I've created a very small project to embed webfonts into a GWT module. Maybe you could give it a try. It allows you to declare a `FontResource` inside a `ClientBundle` and inject it as a normal CSS. It deploys the font files into the module too, which is very handy. It's a beta version but hope you like it. http://code.google.com/p/gwt-webfonts/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5247

You'd have to put your `@font-face` declaration in an external (not-`CssResource`) stylesheet (could be inlined in you HTML host page for instance)

Comment: Well, my problem is different, as I don't even use CssResource (except if UiBinder converts styles to it internally). I worked it out by importing Google Fonts in main stylesheet, and then just using them in font-family in CSS.

Comment: UiBinder's ui:style are indeed converted to a CssResource (and ui:image into ImageResource, and ui:data into DataResource) in an implicit ClientBundle.

Comment: Thanks Thomas. And to think I was looking for bugs in my code for over 30 minutes... gotta love the random NPE in GWT. The patch for this has been created, but as of last week is still waiting to get into the GWT trunk.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the limitation [Thomas has noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5396034/9686) I've developed a small project to define font resources into GWT clientbundle's. It's still a beta but hopes you like it.

It's on http://code.google.com/p/gwt-webfonts/